# 我一字一字地学习汉语 OR 我一个字一个字地学习汉语

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct use of this grammar pattern?

我一字一字地学习汉语。

我一个字一个字地学习汉语。

The first one feels correct to me. The pattern is:

```
一{MW,N}一{MW,N} + 地 + V
```

Comment: Both are fine. 我一个字一个字地学习汉语 is stronger than the other one in the sense that 一个字一个字地 emphasizes you learn each Chinese word by "个".

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. However, I cannot mark the question as answered unless you answer it. :)

Comment: Both are acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are correct, but the second one sounds more natural to a native speaker.

`个` is omitted only in some idiomatic phrases like `一字一句` or `一字排开`(though here `一` doesn't mean the number, but the shape of the number).

In Chinese, it's more idiomatic to use a `measure word` between the number and the noun in most cases.

Comment: To be clear, you are a never speaker, correct?

Comment: You mean NATIVE speaker? Yes, I am a Chinese, so my English may be not so 'native'.

Comment: Yes, native speaker.* :) And from your comment at least, your English seems quite good. That's why I wasn't sure!

Answer (score 5):

As other people have pointed out, both versions are correct. However, I prefer the second one (一个字一个字) for two reasons:

1. 一个字一个字 has a stronger emphasis on learning by INDIVIDUAL characters, and thus implies a higher degree of difficulty and diligence.
2. number + noun (without MW inbetween) is a somewhat archaic structure. As such, it is more frequently seen in set phrases. Therefore, when a native speaker of Chinese sees the first 一字, he tends to think of idioms that contains this expression, for instance 一字一句, 一字一顿...  This may cause a mild diversion.

Answer (score 2):

Both are OK.

As a native speaker, I prefer the second one.

From your question, I gather that we have something in common when it comes to learning a foreign language. But now, I have begun to understand that grammar is not so important. Like you, I paid a lot of attention to English grammar while learning....

As for this question, nobody will care about this detail.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Someone else was asking about this issue and I wasn't sure, so I put the question here. :)

I agree—grammar isn't the most important; it's better to focus on speaking and immersion (being in the country or listening/reading a lot of media). Best of luck!